# Limit file uploads to mp3 and WAV

Tags: php, file, upload

I use this code to limit upload of images.

How do I use the same code to limit uploads of only mp3 and WAV files?

Thank you so much!

```
if ((($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["Artwork"]["size"] < 20000000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["Artwork"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    //echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["Artwork"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }else{
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Artwork"]["tmp_name"],
      $path_image . $imageName);
      }
    }else{
    //echo "invalid file";
    }
```

Comment: There is an accept tag you would use in the input file html but alas no browser supports it ... http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `$_FILES["Artwork"]["type"]`, this is specified by the client, and he can put anything he wants here.

Answer (score 0):

As said, don't use $_FILES["file"]["type"], it's not safe. 
Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php instead (see example, it's quite self-explanatory).

To know the mimetype of MP3 and WAV file, search here: http://www.asciitable.it/mimetypes.asp